# Скрыть форму после авторизации без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать скрытие формы после авторизации без использования JS.На данный момент после логирования, она находится снизу под формой "Написать пост".  (форма "Написать пост" появляется после успешного входа) Код:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> Log In</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#999">
  <?php
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="submit"){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, content) values ('".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['post']."')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    sleep(3);
    header("location:index.php");
  }  


if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="LOGIN"){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin where user='".$_POST['user']."' and password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    sleep(2);
    $log = $stmt->rowCount();
} else {
    $log=0;
}

if($log==1){
    echo "<center>Welcome, ".$_POST['user']." </center>";
    ?>
    <div class="postform">
      <form method="POST" action="" class="formpost">
        Title:<input class="title" type="text" name="title"> Content:
        <textarea rows="5" cols="25" class="textarea" name="post"></textarea><br>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
        <div class="loginform">
          <form method="POST" action="">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input name="user"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"></td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял и правильно понял код) то в $log у вас статус авторизации.

```
$log == 1 // авторизован
$log == 0 // не авторизован
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Log In</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#999">
  <?php
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="submit"){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, content) values ('".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['post']."')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    sleep(3);
    header("location:index.php");
  }  


if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="LOGIN"){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin where user='".$_POST['user']."' and password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    sleep(2);
    $log = $stmt->rowCount();
} else {
    $log=0;
}

if($log==1){
    echo "<center>Welcome, ".$_POST['user']." </center>";
    ?>
    <div class="postform">
      <form method="POST" action="" class="formpost">
        Title:<input class="title" type="text" name="title"> Content:
        <textarea rows="5" cols="25" class="textarea" name="post"></textarea><br>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {?>
    <div class="loginform">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input name="user"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"></td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, все верно. $log == 1 // авторизован. Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Стоит отметить, что при использовании php в html лучше использовать конструкции вида `<?php if($log==1) : ?>`, `<?php else : ?>`, `<?php endif; ?>`, `<?= $_POST['user']; ?>` и т. д. Это значительно увеличит читаемость кода.